# How can I translate hint text in GetX?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I want to translate my hint text, but I don't know how. Is there a way I can translate this?

```
InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
    searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'country_code',)) // How can I translate this in GetX?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to prepare your `GetMaterialApp`:

```
GetMaterialApp(
    translationsKeys:AppTranslation.translationsKeys,
    locale: Get.deviceLocale,
    fallbackLocale: Locale("en" , "US").
    title: "Application"
    initialRoute: Routes.HOME,
    defaultTransition: Transition.fade,
    onGenerateRoute:RouteGenerator.generateRoute,)
```

Then create a `AppTranslation.dart`:

```
//AppTranslation.dart
abstract class AppTranslation {
  static Map<String, Map<String, String>> translationsKeys = {
    "en_US": enUS,
    "fr": fr
  };
}

final Map<String, String> enUS = {
  'greeting': 'Hello, How are you?',
  'day': "Awesome day..."
};

final Map<String, String> fr = {
  'greeting': "Salut comment allez-vous?",
  'day': "Super journée..."
};
```

To change the locale:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(languageCode); //languageCode=en_US or fr
Get.updateLocale(locale);
```

And you can call translation text like that:

```
Text(
    'greeting'.tr,
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have seen this but I don't think I can add a text widget to a hint text

Comment: just add `hintText: 'country_code'.tr`

Comment: @RandalSchwartz why ?

Answer (score -1):

```
hintText: ("greeting".tr).toString()
```